# Spring boot deploy as ROOT in tomcat stuck at deploying

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have issue while deploying my Spring boot application in Linux server.

I built the project as war file and renamed it to **ROOT.war**.

After placing the **ROOT.war** in webapps folder and starting `tomcat` service, It got stuck at this stage and nothing happens.

```
09-Jan-2019 09:27:10.503 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/home/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
```

I checked possible solution over web and also added the `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` property.

I got dump from the `jstack`. But I am not able to understand what could be the issue here.

Here is the output after I started the tomcat server

```
09-Jan-2019 09:26:51.998 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 3 2018 17:39:20 UTC
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.002 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.35.0
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.002 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191-amd64/jre
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/tomcat
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/tomcat
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.005 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.005 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.007 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.007 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.009 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.009 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.009 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/tomcat
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/tomcat
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.011 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/tomcat/temp
09-Jan-2019 09:26:52.011 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
09-Jan-2019 09:27:00.000 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
09-Jan-2019 09:27:00.595 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Jan-2019 09:27:01.317 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Jan-2019 09:27:01.576 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Jan-2019 09:27:01.577 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 31920 ms
09-Jan-2019 09:27:06.322 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-Jan-2019 09:27:06.322 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
09-Jan-2019 09:27:10.503 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/home/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
```

For `jstack` logs, Please check here https://textuploader.com/1aoh0

UPDATE

`<build>` from `pom.xml`

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Yes already tried with that. Same issue

Comment: It's not working when you name the war `ROOT` ? Is that what you want to say ? If no, can you add your `<build>` from your `pom.xml`

Comment: @GabLeg Yes, If i name it as app.war then its deploying well. Adding `<build>` in question.

Comment: I just renamed one of my war to `ROOT.war` like you did and it didn't works too. The problem is that there is already a `ROOT` folder in webapps. I deleted it for test purpose and like I expected, it deployed the application when I retried it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is anywhere related to running the war file as ROOT. You should be able to fix this issue by making one small change in catalina.sh

1. Open catalina.sh file in the bin folder of Tomcat.
2. Search for JAVA_OPTS and add the following,
   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

Eg:, JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"

3. Save catalina.sh and restart tomcat.

Hopefully you should not face the same issue now.

Comment: I already have added that. You can check that in tomcat log I have posted.
`-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`